# Build Xamarin project in IOS which Created in Windows

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms application in windows , I want to get IPA file , is it possible copy the  solution to mac pc and build that project and get the IPA file

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/index

Comment: yes in short words, and you can also build the project using AppStore build configuration and you will find it in the bin folder on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a Mac to build iOS apps to publish to the store.  You also need a Mac to debug the app from visual studio.

VSTS does have a hosted Mac build agent you can use to build the iOS app.